# Flutter unfocus SearchAnchor.bar to remove the keyboard

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have an essential ability to unfocus `SearchAnchor.bar` from some function body. A common answer to this question is to use `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();` but it doesn't work in this case:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MainApp());

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: SearchAnchor.bar(
            barHintText: 'Start typing here',
            isFullScreen: false,
            suggestionsBuilder: (context, controller) {
              return [
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Click me'),
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.closeView(null);
                    FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                  },
                ),
              ];
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see tapping on the `ListTile` does close search view but it doesn't unfocus `SearchAnchor.bar` completely—the keyboard is still active.

I can achieve the desired effect by using this code instead of simply `FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();`:

```
await Future.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 1),
  () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
);
```

But this looks like a dirty hack and I'm looking for more official solution.

---

Edited: **SOLUTION** from [@rhpekarek answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77687624/7221300):

```
FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use a postFrameCallback but you could use a FocusScope and FocusNode if you want to be explicit.

Option 1:

```
ListTile(
 title: const Text('Click me'),
 onTap: () {
   controller.closeView(null);
   WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
     FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
   });
 },
),
```

Option 2:

```
 final FocusScopeNode focusNode = FocusScopeNode();
 bool didJustDismiss = false;
 
 MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FocusScope(
          node: focusNode,
          onFocusChange: (isFocused) {
            if (didJustDismiss && isFocused) {
              didJustDismiss = false;
              focusNode.unfocus();
            }
          },
          child: SearchAnchor.bar(
            barHintText: 'Start typing here',
            isFullScreen: false,
            suggestionsBuilder: (context, controller) {
              return [
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Click me'),
                  onTap: () {
                    didJustDismiss = true;
                    controller.closeView(null);
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                  },
                ),
              ];
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: Wow, `FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();` from Option 1 did the trick even without wrapping it in `postFrameCallback`. Thanks a lot!